# Downloading video file by streaming a certain part of the video

Tags: java, video, stream, decoding, jcodec

An online link gives me back a video in my browser, that is then streamed. In my browser, I don't need to download the whole video to visualize it - I can skip to a certain part, visualize that part, and even stop watching before the end.

How can I, from the very same link, start to stream from a specific time onwards until another specific time, and each time save every frame I received to a video file?

I do know that I need to decode the data I get.
I also know that I need to somehow access the metadata of the video file.
However, I don't know how to deal with it in practice.

I tried out JCodec, but could not find how to deal with internet streams instead of opening files.
How can I properly stream parts of an online video, frame-by-frame, while also having access to metadata such as total video length, resolution, and FPS?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first parts of your question:

1. [Trim videos](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/video_manipulation_and_delivery#trimming_videos) with start offset and either end offset or duration (in seconds, percentages, etc.), e.g. http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/video/upload/so_6.5,eo_10/dog.mp4
2. [Grab frames](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/video_manipulation_and_delivery#generating_video_thumbnails) at desired timestamps along the original video, e.g. http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/video/upload/so_8.5/dog.jpg to save a JPEG-format frame at 8.5 seconds from the start of the video.

Comment: I'd like to use a library and my own java code though, without going through third party services. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: You're welcome, clearly there are simple use cases where using your own code makes sense. However, once you start being concerned with supporting multiple image formats, custom quality settings, optimized compression, filters/effects, responsive images, etc. it becomes rather unwieldy to rely on your own code, which is where 3rd-party services shine. You have good choices available and they're fairly easy to use.